# How to automate this process?

Tags: perl, macos, terminal

It involves rewriting .htm to .txt (output file)

then using a parser (stanford grammar parser) (output file)

for all the files in a directory.

MY QUESTION: I would like to get all the files in the directory, without doing it manually, and find a way to run the parser, without having to type it into the Terminal for each file.

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use HTML::FormatText;
use HTML::TreeBuilder;

my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new->parse_file("chpt15Intro.htm");

use HTML::FormatText;

my $formatter = HTML::FormatText->new(leftmargin => 0, rightmargin => 1000);
   #print $formatter->format($tree); is replaced by push
push (my @files, $formatter->format($tree));
foreach my $files (@files) {
    $files =~ s/^\s+//mg;
    open MYFILE, ">ch15Intro.txt"; 
    select MYFILE; 
    print $files;
}
```

In the **Terminal**, after getting the html file converted, I write:

```
script parsedch15Intro.txt ./lexparser.csh ch15Intro.txt
```

to save the output of the parser. This step still needs automation.

I'm a beginner so thanks for any advice.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What part are you having difficulties with? When asking for help, state what you want/expect and what you have/is happening. Make sure to describe the overall goal in addition to the particular issue you're having. Read ["Writing the Perfect Question"](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) for more guidelines.

Comment: @outis: Sorry, I'm still learning, I have updated the question, let me know if more is needed

Comment: Your indent for "my $tree = HTML..." is throwing me off a bit. Assuming you are not doing anything special I am missing I will have an answer for you in a bit.

Comment: Would File::Find be a good option?

Comment: Don't write answers in the question. Write answers as answers. And accept them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it from your question that what you want to do is to apply this script to all the (html-) files in a certain folder, and output text versions of them.

So a simple solution is to simply replace the hardcoded file names with variables, and loop the script around the `@ARGV`, e.g. the arguments to the script, like so:

```
for my $file (@ARGV) {
    next unless ($file =~ /^(.+).html*$/i);
    my $outfile = $1 . ".txt";
    my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new;
    $tree->parse_file($file); # credit to Phil for this one
    my $formatter = HTML::FormatText->new(leftmargin => 0, rightmargin => 1000);
    foreach my $files ($formatter->format($tree)) {
        $files =~ s/^\s+//mg;
        open my $fh, '>', $outfile or die $!; 
        print $fh $files;
    }
}
```

As you see, I cleaned up some of it. Use like so:

```
> script.pl *.htm
```

Comment: Awesome!! I love the paste-in-and-go answers!! Thanks a lot. I can definitely move on from here to get the parser in as well

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing line 6 (`my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new->parse_file("chpt15Intro.htm");`) with this:

```
my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new;
$tree->parse_file("chpt15Intro.htm");
```

The CPAN docs for HTML::TreeBuilder don't mention what the return value of `parse_file` is, if any, but I suspect that it's **not** the instance that the method was called on. This means that after the call, your `$tree` variable isn't anything meaningful.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass multiple files via the command line using [globbing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29), which the shell will expand.

```
./lexparser *.html
```

All file names ending in '.html' are then available in `@ARGV`. If your script is to take only file names as arguments, simply loop over `@ARGV` to get each input file name, processing the input file in the loop body. For example:

```
for my $in (@ARGV) {
    my $out = $in;
    $out =~ s/(\.html?)?$/.txt/;
    ...
}
```

If you want your script to take additional options (such as to set the extension for the output files, or to set a prefix or suffix for output files), process `@ARGV` before processing the files. You can write your own [option processor](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=88222) or use one of the [`Getopt`](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=Getopt&mode=module) modules.

Note: an extension of '.csh' indicates a C shell script. For Perl, use '.pl' if you want to use an extension at all (it's usually unnecessary, as the shebang line carries information as to the script type).

Comment: Thanks for helping! Especially with the knowledge and links. I'm sure it'll help with doing a multiple-file-parse

Comment: Also, the globbing didn't work as is, since the Terminal command 'script' requires an output file name argument first, which I want to match the * in your: _*.html_ 

So I'm working on that now...

Comment: @Jon: the first two lines in the loop body handle that: generate the output file name rather than passing it on the command line. As mentioned, you could also support customizing the output file name by setting a prefix, suffix or the extension from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Not a perl solution, but you can do it as a one-liner with this shell pipeline,

assuming

- you have the text-only browser *lynx* installed (is it available on the mac?)
- and there is a *sh* Shell on your system:

  ls -1 mydir/*.html | xargs -i sh -c "lynx -dump '{}' > '{}.txt'"

this creates a bunch of *.html.txt files in the same directory. And the text might be not formatted according to your requirements

Comment: Cool stuff, thanks for the option. I just started learning Perl, now I want to learn shell script too, powerful stuff!

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**: Here is the answer to automating the parser: (similar to TLP and outis' solutions)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

for my $file (@ARGV) {
    next unless ($file =~ /^(.+).txt*$/i); ##file name ends in txt
    my $outfile = "parsed$1".".txt";
    qx/script -q \/Users\/jon\/Desktop\/stanford-postagger-full-2011-04-20\/$outfile \.\/lexparser.csh $file/;
}
##First in Terminal cd /Users/jon/Downloads/chpt1-8 or whichever directory this perl script and all texfiles and parser files are
##Called in Terminal by ==>  perl auto_parse.pl *.txt

##This saves the output to directory spedicifed. The output is the parsed files
##Required: stanford parser files in same directory as this script
```